# How to get number of PK used as FK?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, primary-key, constraint

How to get number of PK used as FK?

Table 1 has a column ID (PK).
Table 2 & 3 has a column ID (FK - refers Table 1 PK).

How to get Value 1 (PK) has used in table 2 & 3 or not without referring table 2 or 3 ?

Comment: Unclear.  If a record appears in a Table2 or Table3, then the [same] Foreign Key value *must* appear in Table1, assuming your constraints are working properly.

Comment: Is your question: Given a value in table_1, in which of table_2 OR table_3 does it appear? Or maybe also neither the two?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id 
FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table2
              WHERE table1.id = table2.id)
  AND /* OR */
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table3
              WHERE table1.id = table3.id)
```

When you need `id`s which are present both in `table1` and `table3`, use `AND`.

When you need `id`s which are present at least in one of these tables, use `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot determine which keys are referenced and which are not without looking up the referencing tables (tables 2 and 3 in your example). There is just no such information stored in the referenced table's data or metadata. The mere fact that you have declared a foreign key from one table to another does not, unfortunately, give you the ability to extract this kind of information without hitting the referencing table.

You can use [Akina's suggestion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/233251/6965) as one way to find the keys that are being referenced. You can also use the `IN` predicate:

```
SELECT id
FROM table1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
   OR id IN (SELECT id FROM table3)
   OR ...  /* repeat as many times as there are referencing tables */
```

And here is another method, using set operators `INTERSECT` and `UNION`:

```
(
  SELECT id FROM table1
  INTERSECT
  SELECT id FROM table2
)

UNION

(
  SELECT id FROM table1
  INTERSECT
  SELECT id FROM table3
)

UNION

... /* repeat as many times as there are referencing tables */
```

A small note regarding the last query: `INTERSECT` has higher precedence than `UNION` in PostgreSQL, which means the above query would work the same without the brackets. Still, using the brackets makes your intention clearer, which is never a bad thing in query writing.